# Can I migrate from sql azure business database edition (old) to sql azure standard database edition (new in preview)?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an export .bacpac file from a sql azure business database edition and I want import that file to sql azure standard database edition.

I have tried through Azure but I think that is not supported yet.

I have also tried through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 but Wizard only shows me old editions "web" and "business" for destination database and it is incompatible...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone answer me in Microsoft forums:

> You're right that today you can't easily change an existing web or
>   business SQL Database into one of the new service tiers.  However that
>   will change in a few days.  We have an update that is being deployed
>   that will allow you to change an existing DB into Basic/Standard.
>
> Until that update is done, we have guidance on using Export/Import
>   into the new service tiers.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741340.aspx
>
> Thanks Guy

Comment: I just checked my account and it appears that the update mentioned in the Microsoft forum that you quoted is now live.  Although I haven't tried upgrading to the new tiers, I now have the option to select Basic, Standard, and Premium in addition to Web and Business.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the alert, I'll try it now.

Comment: Where do you find the upgrade option?

Comment: First, someone with administrator account must request access to preview of "New Services Tiers for SQL Databases". After, inside your database/Scale, new options will appear: "basic", "standard" and "premium" to the right of "web" and "basic".